# What does the syntax "|&" mean in shell language?

Tags: linux, shell

Recently, I am installing the PC^2 on my Ubuntu14.04LTS to make up our university's ACM-ICPC Contest environment. But when I run the shell file "pc2server", the system gives me an error alert which is

```
pc2server: 27: pc2server: Syntax error: "&" unexpected
```

So I check the file pc2server and find the line 27. I found that the code is

```
java -d64 -version |& grep -q "Error" && JAVA32=1
```

I know what syntax `|` and `&` means， but what I only just want to know is that what syntax `|&` means.

Comment: What has become of the good tradition of reading the fine manual?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From the bash man page:

> #### Pipelines
>
> A pipeline is a sequence of one or more commands separated by one of the control operators `|` or `|&`. The format for a pipeline is:
>
> ```
> [time [-p]] [ ! ] command [ [|│|&] command2 ... ]
> ```
>
> The standard output of command is connected via a pipe to the standard input of command2.  This connection is performed before any redirections specified by the command (see REDIRECTION below).  **If `|&` is used, the standard error of command is  connected  to command2’s standard input through the pipe; it is shorthand for `2>&1 |`**.  This implicit redirection of the standard error is performed after any redirections specified by the command.

Check your hash-bang line. Plain sh doesn't support `|&`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but now I find that if I delete the `&` or replace the `|&` to the `2>&1 |`, the shell code will be right. Why?

Comment: What shell does the script use? It must be one that doesn't support `|&`.

Comment: It is the Bourne shell. The PC^2 system http://pc2.ecs.csus.edu/ is developed by California State University and I think maybe they would not make mistakes.

Comment: What is the hash-bang line: `#!/bin/sh`? `#!/bin/bash`? Other? Plain `sh` doesn't support `|&`.

Comment: The hash-bang line is `#!/bin/sh`. (`sh` is the Bourne shell,`bash` is the Bourne again shell). I think I got it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Please check answer of John. Here I am adding example for detail understating.

```
# cat /tmp/test1
cat: /tmp/test1: No such file or directory
# cat /tmp/test1 2> /dev/null | grep "No such file or directory"
# cat /tmp/test1 2> /dev/null |& grep "No such file or directory"
cat: /tmp/test1: No such file or directory
```

First command returns error as file does not exist (stderr output from command).

Second command do not return any output as stderr of *cat* command is redirect */dev/null*, so *grep* command do not get stderr of *cat* command through pipe.

Third command returns output even stderr of *cat* command is redirected to */dev/null* because of pipe with ampersand (|&). It connects stdout and stderr  of command1 to command2’s stdin; The implicit redirection of the standard error is performed after any redirections specified by the command.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to commend [the third example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65796341/11289474) given by Nils:

```bash
#cat /tmp/test1 2> /dev/null |& grep "No such file or directory"
cat: /tmp/test1: No such file or directory
```

`|&` is shorthand for `2>&1 |` as John Kugelman mentioned above, so `stderr` (the descriptor `2`) of the command `cat /tmp/test1` is redirected to the pipe `|`, not the `/dev/null` no longer, thus
`grep` can receive the output of `stderr` but `/dev/null` cannot.

Another example explaining that:

```bash
bash-4.2$ cat /tmp/test1 2> a.txt 2> b.txt
bash-4.2$ cat a.txt 
bash-4.2$ cat b.txt
cat: /tmp/test1: No such file or directory
```

The output is because the second redirection statement `2> a.txt` overrides the first statement `2> a.txt`.